# The points of inflection are of order $1$ or $3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I'm currently working on the book of Kirwan about "Complex algebraic curves" I don't understand this part of chapter 6.2:

[image]

I don't understand, why we can conclude that the point of inflection on $C_{\Lambda}$ are precisely the points of order $1$ or $3$. I guess, that order $3$ comes from the fact, that $p+p+p=0$ iff $p$ is an inflection point but what about order $1$? There we know nothing or do I oversee something?

Comment: In an additive group the fact that $3p=0$ does not say that $p$ has order $3$, only that its order divides $3$.

Comment: I just say that $p$ has a multiplicity of $3$ if it is an inflection point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group element $p$ has order $n$ if $np = \overbrace{p + p + \dotsm + p}^{n \text{ times}}= 0$ and $mp \ne 0$ for $m < n$ (and given $np = 0$ you only need to check for $m$ dividing $n$).

So if $3p = p + p + p = 0$ (which as explained is equivalent to the point $p$ being an inflection point of the curve) you have two cases: if also $ p = 0$ then it has order $1$, otherwise it has order $3$. Conversely in either case $3p = 0$.